# ModuleNotFound error while executing a package created by PyInstaller On Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, boto

I am packaging my ML solution which includes keras and tensorflow using PyInstaller. The exe builts just fine but when I execute the exe it gives an `ModuleNotFoundError for boto`. The solution works just fine if I run it using the script. All the dependencies were installed.

Here is my spec file:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('data\\*.tsv', 'data')],
             hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors.typedefs','sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree','sklearn.tree._utils'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

Here is the error:

> File "site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 44, in    File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\catalogai\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 627, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\smart_open__init__.py", line 28, in    File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\catalogai\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 627, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py", line 39, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto' [9628] Failed to execute
>   script main

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) sometimes PyInstaller cannot find the imported modules and include them in your executable output. The solution is simple:

> To find these hidden imports, build the app with the `-v` flag (Getting Python’s Verbose Imports above) and run it.
>
> Once you know what modules are needed, you add the needed modules to the bundle using the `--hidden-import=` command option, or by editing the spec file, or with a hook file (see Understanding PyInstaller Hooks below).

Just add your missing modules to `hiddenimports`.

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('data\\*.tsv', 'data')],
             hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors.typedefs','sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree','sklearn.tree._utils','boto`],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

Comment: It worked for me.Although I had to went through many dependencies to figure out them. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Have you try to manually install boto module `pip install boto3` [boto documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation) first have pip installed

Comment: edit the script rename the import `import boto3` . did you try that..? rename the at the method call as well