# FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] when running pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am trying to make my python file as an executable using Pyinstaller. After the process of conversion has finished, in my dist folder, when I click on "myApplication.exe" I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Application\\dist\\myApplication\\smart_open\\VERSION'
[17416] Failed to execute script myApplication`

I've already searched for answers to this but none of them have the specific error as mine which is the folder `smart_open\VERSION` as I have no idea what that's supposed to be.

**EDIT**

The `smart_open` folder does not even exists in my `myApplication` folder

Comment: Is VERSION a text file with the version number in it?

Comment: I do not even have the `smart_open` folder in the first place to have `VERSION`, not sure what is happening

Comment: Do your application use the pip package [smart_open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/)?

Comment: The package is in the `Lib\site-packages` folder, however my application is not importing it, unless some other library has it as a dependancy? not sure.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088998) can help you, it is about hidden import. Is there a version file in the `Lib\site-packages\smart_open`?

Comment: Yes there is, should i just copy the entire `smart_open` package?

Comment: copying the folder `smart_open` has solved the issue, thank you

Comment: Abdane, could you post the solution and show how you imported a working version of smart_open into the compiled app?  I'm hitting into the same issues you faced.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add the `VERSION` file of `smart_open` in the `spec` file. More information in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

**Edit**

In this case, `datas` line should be:

```py
datas=[ ('c:\\python360564\\lib\\site-packages\\smart_open\\VERSION', 'smart_open\\VERSION' )],
```

The first part is the initial path of the file and the second the destination path (get from the error message).

Comment: I tried the technique (several different ways) you mentioned above @ndclt but it wasn't working for me.  I essentially did this in the ".spec" file ```datas=[ ('c:\\python360564\\lib\\site-packages\\smart_open\\VERSION', '.' )], ``` and the error still occurred.

Comment: I think the `.` of the second expression in the tuple should be replaced. I edited my answer with a try.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the original version of "smart_open" use this fork of the library: https://github.com/rs-trevor/smart_open

The pull request is here: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/pull/344

It essentially converts the strange (extension-less) "VERSION" file into "version.py" so pyinstaller picks it up correctly

I encountered the same issue posted it within the smart_open github: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/issues/345